# How to use substring in controller?

Tags: c#, arrays, substring

I am trying to split name in firstname, middlename and lastname. For this I need to split the name. I am doing it in controller only.

Here is my code:

```
var name = c1.Split(' ');
String fname  = name[0];
String mname = null;
String lname = null;

if(name.Length == 2) //first and last names provided
{
    fname = name[0];
    lname = name[1];
}                

if(name.Length > 2) //first item is the first name. last item is the last name. Everything else are middle names
{
    fname = name[0];
    mname = name.Substring(1, name.Length-2);
    lname = name[name.Length-1];
}
```

But in controller it says that substring is not defined. What can do?

Comment: `Substring` against a string array doesn't supported. It is necessary to provide index to return a string before use `Substring` then choose starting index and length.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling Substribg on an array. Call it on c1 instead.

Comment: This won't give the desired result (middle names) but a string starting with the second character of the first name. (and most of the time the result will *only* be a substring of the first name)

Answer (score 0):

You are using substring on collection of data and not on string.
Your code should look like

```
    fname.Substring(...)
```

or

```
    name[0].substring
```

Comment: This won't give the desired result (middle names) but just a substring of the first name (and theoretically could result in an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the first name has less characters than the array has elements)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the first element of your array as *first name*, the last one as *last name* and the elements between the first and last element **joined together** as *middle name*:

```
fname = name[0];
mname = string.Join(" ",name.Skip(1).Take(name.Length-2).ToArray());
lname = name[name.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring can be used for string
you used for an array

```
 if(name.length)
 {
     fname = name[0];
     mname = name[1].Substring(1, name[1].Length-2);
     lname = name[name.Length-1];          
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            var pieces = c1.Split(' ');
            if (pieces.Length == 2)
            {
                var firstname = pieces[0];
                var lastname = pieces[1];
            }

            if (pieces.Length > 2)
            {
                var firstname = pieces[0];
                var lastname = pieces[pieces.Length -1 ];

                var middlename = string.Join(" ", pieces.Skip(1).Take(pieces.Length - 2));

            }
```